# Real-Time Priority in the user namespace

Tags: namespace, real-time

I have a small program starting a thread with realtime priority in a user-namespace. But every time I want to start it, I get an errno "Permission denied". The program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   printf("Setting rt prio\n");

   struct sched_param param;
   param.sched_priority=20;
   int retval = sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_RR, &param);
   printf("Retval: %d, Errno: %d\n", retval, errno);

   return 0;
}
```

Running the program as root brings the expected output:

> ```
>  Setting rt prio
>  Retval: 0, Errno: 0
> ```

Running as a normal user works with the necessary capabilities:

> ```
>  sudo setcap CAP_SYS_NICE+eip realtime
> ```

But when I switch to a user namespace with unshare -U, I always get the error permission denied. Even when I set the appropriate capability in the parent namespace.
Is there some kind of way to run a thread with real-time priority in the user-namespace?